# Use of cox model in risk prediction

Tags: survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am new in data science. I want to understand the cox-based risk prediction used in cardiovascular disease. I read the example presented in the appendix of this[1] paper. The following equation is used:
[2]. The calculation to compute the second parameter in the exp is presented as follows:

= 2.083643 ∗ 3.768 − 0.469719 ∗ 1.548

- 0.608864 ∗ 3.230 + 0.241461 ∗ 0.1469
- 1.682571 ∗ 4.913 − 0.302090 ∗ 4.311
- 0.009669 ∗ 13.96 + 1.087501 ∗ 0.02001
  = 16.518741

My question is how they get 3.768,
1.548, 3.230, 0.1469, 4.913, 4.311, 13.96, 0.02001

Any help please.
[1]: https://doi.org/10.1155/2019/8392348
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rob4.jpg